# Google API, Facebook API,YouTube API not working with Android Studio 2.1.2

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I recently updated my android Studio from version 1.5.1 to version 2.1.2. But ever since I've done that, my app no longer seems to be able to login with google or facebook. Neither would the Youtube API work. Is there a way around this problem or should i be looking to revert back to Android Studio 1.5.1 till 2.1.2 becomes more stable?

Or maybe it is because of SDK update to android N? Though I don't think that is the problem since the gradle files still compile the project with the previous build settings